# dyld: Library not loaded: AdjustSdk.framework

Tags: ios, xcode, dyld

I have get build error after adding Adjust SDK framework to my project.

Error like below:

*dyld: Library not loaded: .framework/AdjustSdk
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/ADB9806B-4B6F-4EEE-88CC-BC66DA8207D3/LCWaikiki.app/LCWaikiki
Reason: image not found*

Answer (score 1):

**For solution i followed the steps below:**

- Add the AdjustSDK.framework to the "Embedded Binaries" section of the "General" tab of the Xcode project settings.
- Close Xcode
- Delete derived data : Open Terminal and enter below command: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Clean project
- Rebuild

---

Comment: What to do if my Application is Command Line Tool and there isn't "Embedded Binaries" in the "General" tab?

Comment: @IhorSkliar i did not experince your situation so i do not any idea about command line tool application. Sorry.