# Library not loaded in ios

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, ios-frameworks

I'm facing problem while running my app. Here is the log of app.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Some.framework/Some
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/291BEF2B-BA81-4864-AB26-AD164537C440/Some.app/Some
>   Reason: image not found

Here are some solutions which I found.
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426590/3110026), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30979099/3110026).

By referencing these I've added Framwork to "Embedded Binaries" under "General" tab.

But by doing so I'm getting another error at the time of making archive. Which is as below.

> Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21

For solving this I've visited some links which are [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34265996/3110026)
Which is saying remove framework from "Embedded Binaries" under "General" tab.

Please help me to solve these errors.

I'm having custom framework in my project.
I'm using Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 0):

Add your framework to "Copy Files" build phase with setting "Frameworks" as destination. This is alternate way to solve problem with

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/...

Comment: "Copy Files" not appearing in Build phase

Comment: Did you add it like here? https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-iOS/wiki/How-to-Add-a-Copy-Files-Build-Phase-in-Xcode-5